# Azure Active Directory's library get "Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0" error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Azure Active Directory's library get "Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0" error.

> Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0

build.gradle(Module:app):

```
 dependencies {
         //MSAL
            implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:4.0.5'
            implementation 'com.microsoft.identity:common:8.0.3'
            implementation 'com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0'
        
            implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:5.40.0'
        
            implementation 'com.azure:azure-identity:1.7.0-beta.2'
    }
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MicrosoftDeviceSDK/DuoSDK-Public/_packaging/Duo-SDK-Feed/maven/v1'
        }
        maven {
            name "vsts-maven-adal-android"
            url "https://identitydivision.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/AndroidADAL/maven/v1"
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_USERNAME") != null ? System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_USERNAME") : project.findProperty("vstsUsername")
                password System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_ACCESSTOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_ACCESSTOKEN") : project.findProperty("vstsMavenAccessToken")
            }
        }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.2"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After I changed gradle.build(module:app) as follow,
everything works now.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    namespace 
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           
        }
        debug{
            
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.0-alpha03"
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    //navigation
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // CameraX core library using the camera2 implementation
    def camerax_version = "1.2.0-rc01"
    // The following line is optional, as the core library is included indirectly by camera-camera2
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"

    //dagger hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'

    //Coroutine
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    //OKHttp3
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.9")
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.9')

    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'

    //MSAL
    implementation ("com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:4.0.5") { exclude group: 'com.microsoft.device.display'}

    implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:5.40.0'
    // Uncomment the line below if you are building an android application
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android'
    // This dependency is only needed if you are using the TokenCrendentialAuthProvider
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-identity:1.7.0-beta.2'
    // To use CallbackToFutureAdapter
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.6.4"
}



kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```